# Selecting MySQL datetime columns which are 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, database, datetime

I'm looking for a simple way to select datetime columns which are 000-00-00 00:00:00 (basically the default unset value).

The following query seems to be working:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE datetimeCol < 1
```

But will this reliably work all the time and across different mysql versions?

Comment: since that represents "invalid", you could just force an invalid date, e.g. `... where datetimeCol = 'foo'` - foo would try to get coerced into a date, fail, and become the all-zeroes value.

Answer (score 8):

I would check for "zero" dates like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE datetimeCol = CONVERT(0,DATETIME)
```

I would prefer the equality predicate over an inequality predicate; it seems to convey my intentions more clearly. And if there are more predicates in the statement, and if the datetimeCol is a leading column in an index, it may help the optimizer make use of a multi-column index.

Answer (score 5):

What about comparing to `0` value:

```
datetimeCol = 0
```

Comment: That's the same as being < 1, no? But are either of these reliable / will work all the time?

Comment: For me `=0` is more obvious. It works for `0000-00-00 00:00:00`;  for `.... 00:01:00` or `.... 00:00:01` it doesn't

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE datetimeCol = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Might seem obvious in hindsight ;)

Comment: That's obvious, but I don't want something that long / with that much chance of typos

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetimeCol) = 0`

Comment: We usually prefer to do the conversion on the literal side, and compare to the raw (native) column. That's because in general, in a predicate,  wrapping a column reference inside a function prevents MySQL from using an index seek or index range scan operation, effectively forcing MySQL to evaluate that function for every row in the table, and the comparing the return the literal. This particular example may be a case where the  MySQL optimizer is able to overcome the usual limitation. For performance reasons, we typically prefer predicates to reference raw columns where possible.